# Chapterstyle in memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

For some reason I can't compile the following small example in memoir.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\chapterstyle{madsen}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}
Text
\chapter{Second chapter}
More text

\end{document}
```

Gives the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \hspace {0.4em}\resizebox 
                                     {!}{4ex}{\chapnamefont \bfseries \sffam...
l.13 \mainmatter
```

If I comment the line `\chapterstyle{madsen}` the document compiles well. I have used `\chapterstyle{madsen}` in other documents before. Why is it that I can't compile this one?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{graphicx}`, as explained in the manual, p. 94, where the chapter style `madsen` is described.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, that fixed it! If you want to rewrite that as an answer, I"ll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The description of the `madsen` chapter style on p. 94 of `memoir`'s manual specifies that

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

is required.